# How to "acces" specific name in HTML

Tags: php, session, html-input

I want to multiply matrixes with PHP and I want user to specify their size.
So i create form and inputs so the user could generate his matrixes.

To upload value of each field in matrix i need different names of inputs in that matrix (do I understand this correctly?)

My function which 'draws' matrix looks like that:

```
    function Draw($matrixName, $rows, $columns){
    echo '<table> Matrix '.$nazwa.'<br>';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++){
        echo '<td>';
        for ($j = 0; $j < $columns; $j++){
            echo '<tr><input type="number" name="'.$nazwa.$i.$j.'"></tr>';          
        }
        echo '</td><br>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
```

And here is my question. How do I acces to this name or input value later?

I've tried this:

```
    function UploadData($name, $rows, $columns){
    $matrix = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++){
        for ($j = 0; $j < $columns; $j++){
            $matrix[$i][$j] = $_POST['$name.$i.$j'];
        }
    }
    return $matrix;
}
```

But it seems that my $matrix is empty. When i do this

```
var_dump($matrix[$i][$j]);
```

or that

```
var_dump($_POST['$matrix[$i][$j]']);
```

my browser says it's NULL.

So tell me please where im making a mistake because I'm stuck..

I keep my variables in $_SESSION so i call this functions like this:

```
$MatrixA = UploadData("A", $_SESSION['$rowsA'], $_SESSION['$columnsA']);
```

and before this operation my values $_SESSION['$rowsA'] and $_SESSION['$columnsA'] are not null (I've checked with var_dump).

Comment: wow, your html output would be completely messed up and not a valid table. I would be very surprised if the browser showed anything remotely looking like a table. But to help out, `$_POST['$name.$i.$j']` should likely be using double quotes. In php, `'$i'` with single quotes is the literal string `$i`. Double quotes will parse variables for their values so `"$i"` would be whatever value was inside `$i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First corrected you table matrix generation, by putting the "tr" and "td" tags properly, Secondly, the first argument needs to be same what you are using as 'name', changed that from '$matrixName' to '$nazwa'

```
function Draw($nazwa, $rows, $columns){
    echo '<table> Matrix '.$nazwa.'<br>';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++){
        echo '<tr>';
        for ($j = 0; $j < $columns; $j++){
            echo '<td><input type="number" name="'.$nazwa.$i.$j.'"></td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Next the line where you are assigning the value from POST, removed the single quotes.

```
function UploadData($name, $rows, $columns){
    $matrix = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++){
        for ($j = 0; $j < $columns; $j++){
            $matrix[$i][$j] = $_POST[ $name . $i .$j ];
        }
    }
    return $matrix;
}
```

Comment: Just as a side note on my answer, as soon as you try to build a matrix higher than 10 by 10 ( either row or cols ), you will start seeing the name being generated duplicates as there is not formatting of numbers to accommodate for two digit numbers. for example, row = 1 col = 11 will be same as row = 11 col=1 buiding the name as 'name111' ;

Comment: Perfect, and `type="number"` should be `type="text"`, too, just for the case $nazwa is non number

Comment: thanks, @justacoder , i left the type="number" as it is, thinking that 'Crixalis' may be looking for a number spinner to enter ..!!